# Force resize of GridView columns inside ListView

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview

I have a `ListView` WPF control with a `GridView`.  I'd like to resize the `GridView` columns when the content of the columns changes.

I have several distinct data sets but when I change from one to another, the size of each columns fits the previous data. I'd like to update dynamically. How can I do that?

Comment: I have the same issue.  Change the data source, and the column widths don't resize.  I'd be happy to set the source and call an AutoSizeColumns method or similar.

Answer (score 29):

Finally, some results on this one. I've found a way to do the same auto-sizing that is done initially and when the gripper on a column header is double clicked.

```
public void AutoSizeColumns()
{
    GridView gv = listView1.View as GridView;
    if (gv != null)
    {
        foreach (var c in gv.Columns)
        {
            // Code below was found in GridViewColumnHeader.OnGripperDoubleClicked() event handler (using Reflector)
            // i.e. it is the same code that is executed when the gripper is double clicked
            if (double.IsNaN(c.Width))
            {
                c.Width = c.ActualWidth;
            }
            c.Width = double.NaN;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Building on top of Oskars answer, here is a blend behavior to automatically size the columns when the content changes.

```
 /// <summary>
 /// A <see cref="Behavior{T}"/> implementation which will automatically resize the automatic columns of a <see cref="ListView">ListViews</see> <see cref="GridView"/> to the new content.
 /// </summary>
 public class GridViewColumnResizeBehaviour : Behavior<ListView>
 {
      /// <summary>
      /// Listens for when the <see cref="ItemsControl.Items"/> collection changes.
      /// </summary>
      protected override void OnAttached()
      {
          base.OnAttached();

          var listView = AssociatedObject;
          if (listView == null)
              return;

          AddHandler(listView.Items);
      }

      private void AddHandler(INotifyCollectionChanged sourceCollection)
      {
          Contract.Requires(sourceCollection != null);

          sourceCollection.CollectionChanged += OnListViewItemsCollectionChanged;
      }

      private void RemoveHandler(INotifyCollectionChanged sourceCollection)
      {
          Contract.Requires(sourceCollection != null);

          sourceCollection.CollectionChanged -= OnListViewItemsCollectionChanged;
      }

      private void OnListViewItemsCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs notifyCollectionChangedEventArgs)
      {
          var listView = AssociatedObject;
          if (listView == null)
              return;

          var gridView = listView.View as GridView;
          if (gridView == null)
              return;

          // If the column is automatically sized, change the column width to re-apply automatic width
          foreach (var column in gridView.Columns.Where(column => Double.IsNaN(column.Width)))
          {
               Contract.Assume(column != null);
               column.Width = column.ActualWidth;
               column.Width = Double.NaN;
          }
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Stops listening for when the <see cref="ItemsControl.Items"/> collection changes.
      /// </summary>
      protected override void OnDetaching()
      {
          var listView = AssociatedObject;
          if (listView != null)
              RemoveHandler(listView.Items);

          base.OnDetaching();
      }
 }
```

Comment: This behavior does not take into account that it might take some time until the new `ActualWidth` is calculated. Therefore it might happen that `ActualWidth` still is too small to fit the contents.

Comment: @Danielku15 Are you finding that is happening? A small sample would be great so I can work towards fixing this problem.

Comment: I have a ListView bound to an ObservableCollection. I have a control in my CellTemplate that is 40x40pt. Attaching the Behavior executes the OnListViewItemsCollectionChanged method, but the ActualWidth is still too small (25pt in my case). The result: it's cropped. It seems the layoutprocess did not run when the handler is executed.

Comment: Similar to @Danielku15 I have a ListViewBehavior class that implements the ActualWidth, Double.NaN change in the ListView.ItemsChanged event handler. When setting the bound source property to a new collection of items, the Auto columns are calculated but at some later unknown time (so I can't resize a Fill column & columns overflow the ListView width). Remove those lines and Auto columns are calculated when expected and fit the ListView width exactly, but they aren't calculated to the new content.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't there a way to bind to the `ActualWidth` of the column? Something like :

```
<GridViewColumn x:Name="column1" Width="{Binding ElementName=column1, Path=ActualWidth}" />
```

I have tried this and it works only the first time, it seems. No binding error.

Comment: I have also tried :
Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}"

Comment: Yeah, you copy ActualWidth over to Width, which is then the intended width forever. The auto-sizing is disabled at the first time. ActualWidth then never changes again, so the intended width won't either.

Answer (score 1):

If like me you are old and prefer VB.NET then here's Oskars code:

```
Public Sub AutoSizeColumns()
    Dim gv As GridView = TryCast(Me.listview1.View, GridView)
    If gv IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each c As GridViewColumn In gv.Columns
            If Double.IsNaN(c.Width) Then
                c.Width = c.ActualWidth
            End If
            c.Width = Double.NaN
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

This works great in WPF, finally someone has worked this out. Thanks Oskar.

Answer (score -1):

You could measure the longest string in pixels and then adjust the column widths accordingly:

```
Graphics graphics = this.CreateGraphics();
SizeF textSize = graphics.MeasureString("How long am I?", this.Font);
```

If you create an algorithm for sizing each column as a ratio of these lengths, you should get a good result.