# Why isn't a ListView column with auto width updated?

Tags: wpf, listview, layout

I'm using a ListView control that contains custom cell templates to allow editing a value in that cell. When I set a column to auto width, it will adjust the width of the column just once when loading the view. But then the width is never updated when the content changes, i.e. die TextBox control expands as more text is typed into it.

How can I convince the ListView control to keep its column sizes current when the content changes? I mean, what's the use of an auto-size column if it doesn't keep up? This works perfectly in a Grid control, just not in a ListView.

I have created a small demo application that shows the issue. You can download its source code here: (Press Ctrl+S or use the File/Save menu command to download the complete archive)

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8CN0ghdY1SdWFNyYWpxajNzY1E

Comment: The GridView doesn't recalculate column widths when the content is changed. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845269/force-resize-of-gridview-columns-inside-listview) post. It might be useful. On the other hand it would probably be better to use a DataGrid for this instead, since it supports editing out of the box..

Comment: The DataGrid doesn't only look bloated, it also feels so. You need to click three times to edit a value in a dropdown selection. Also the border changes a lot when editing and the entire row height jumps around. That's not exactly a high-quality UI. — The other post explains how to resize the columns, but not when. I'd basically need to attach to size change events of all visual children as they appear (and detach when they're removed), to know when to resize a column.