# How to resize ListView/GridView to contents in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, gridview, resize

I would like to resize columns of a grid view into ListView to contents. There is the XAML code:

```
<ListView x:Name="listViewStatEntries"  
              AlternationCount="2" Grid.Row="8" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Background="White"
              ItemsSource="{Binding StatResult.StatEntries}" >

  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn  Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Param.Speciality}">
        <GridViewColumn.Header>
          <GridViewColumnHeader Content="{Binding Labels[2851]}" Tag="Param.Speciality" Click="listViewStatEntriesColumnHeader_Click" Width="Auto" />
        </GridViewColumn.Header>
      </GridViewColumn>

      <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Alarm}">
        <GridViewColumn.Header>
          <GridViewColumnHeader Content="{Binding Labels[2765]}" Tag="Alarm" Click="listViewStatEntriesColumnHeader_Click" Width="Auto" />
        </GridViewColumn.Header>
      </GridViewColumn>
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>

</ListView>
```

I found this thread: [Force resize of GridView columns inside ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845269/force-resize-of-gridview-columns-inside-listview) and try Oskar solution:

```
public void AutoSizeColumns()
{
  GridView gv = listView1.View as GridView;
  if (gv != null)
  {
    foreach (var c in gv.Columns)
    {
        // Code below was found in GridViewColumnHeader.OnGripperDoubleClicked() event handler (using Reflector)
        // i.e. it is the same code that is executed when the gripper is double clicked
        if (double.IsNaN(c.Width))
        {
            c.Width = c.ActualWidth;
        }
        c.Width = double.NaN;
    }
  }
}
```

But with this solution, columns was resized to visible contents only and not to all data into the ListView. How can I resize column to all data?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Do you mean that width of all columns should be have the most long length?

Comment: Hi StepUp. I need to resize each column to it content. The method works fine for that, but only on visibles items and not on the entire columns. I would like to resize each column to see the most long item!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason they resize only to the visible rows is because you have virtualization on (which is default). Try turning it off

```
<ListView VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"
```

Comment: Work fine! It's exactly what I need. Thank you Dean!