# Image not showing after collapsed

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

I am running into a strange situation where the image won't show up if its visibility is first set to collapsed and latter set to visible through binding.

```
<ListView Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding SystemCheckEntries}">
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding State}" />
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="info.png" 
                               Height="14" 
                               ToolTip="{Binding Message}"
                               Visibility="{Binding Message, Converter={StaticResource StringNullOrEmptyToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Converter:

```
public class StringNullOrEmptyToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty((string) value) ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

if I use `Visibility.Collapsed` in converter then the result looks like
[image]

and if I open up visual tree to check the property of the image
[image]
which says its suppose to be "Visible" (but apparently not)

If I use `Visibility.Hidden` in converter then the result looks like
[image]

Which is exactly what I wanted. But then I don't want the icon to take up extra space when its not showing.

So .. why is this happening?

Comment: I set up a similar minimal example and it works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some conjecture: The first items have no width (because they are collapsed), the `ListView` sets the column width to 0. New items are added that have an image but it's not shown because the column has no width.

**Edit**: Just confirmed this behaviour.

Comment: I tried to set the size to 50x50 after window is rendered. and turned on display layout adorers. I can clearly see the 50x50 box but not the image nor the tooltip

Comment: What did you size 50x50? And what would be the point in `Collapsed` if you set a fixed size anyway?

Comment: theres a new tool in vs2015 which would allow you to modify element's property during run time like browser. I modified the image's size during run time and its still not showing

Comment: Changing the image size does not matter at that point. It's cut off by the column, you need to resize the column.

Comment: I tried expending every single parent and ancestor of the image and still no luck

Comment: You shouldn't do that, the columns are layout controller, you can't just expect modifications like that to work. You need to interact with the column directly.

Comment: You need to invoke something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845269/force-resize-of-gridview-columns-inside-listview

Comment: After lots experiments it seems like you are right. But I feel like this should be considered a bug in WPF

Comment: Maybe, it's certainly not what most people would want if they define a column to auto-size.